# Inserting the selection of radio buttons into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for online to resolve this.

At any rate, I have three radio buttons and I need to push the selection of a single button selected from the list into MySQL.

Currently using the below as my radio buttons & submit:

```
   <input class="radiobutton" type="radio" name="1" id="1">1</div>
   <input class="radiobutton" type="radio" name="2" id="2">2</div>
   <input class="radiobutton" type="radio" name="3" id="3">3</div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">`
```

Can someone help me with the syntax to grab the selected radio button and insert it into MySQL?

An example of the syntax would be
        UPDATE tblwhatever.setting SET value='$x' where setting='Y';

Comment: Give all the radio buttons the same `name` then just use that variable as radio button groups should only have one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
<input class="radiobutton" type="radio" name="radio" id="1" value="1" onclick="document.getElementById('2').checked = false;"/>
<input class="radiobutton" type="radio" name="radio" id="2" value="2" onclick="document.getElementById('1').checked = false;"/>
```

Note that i gave them the same `name` attribute.  When the form is submitted we will retrieve `$_POST['radio']` and the `value` will determine which radio button was selected.  The `onclick` attribute will uncheck the other radio button if selected.. eg: if radio `id="1"` is being checked uncheck `id="2"`

Comment: I'm looking to have the value be a non-numeric value. Seems it's only saving if value="$number". Any ideas?

Comment: just cast it as a string `(string)$value`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm an obvious noob here.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed. Needed single quites around value='$radio' 

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <form method='POST' >
<input class="radiobutton" type="radio" 

name="radio" id="1" value='1' checked>
       <input class="radiobutton" type="radio" 

name="radio" id="2" value='2'>
       <input class="radiobutton" type="radio" 

name="radio" id="3" value='3'>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" 

value="Update">`

</form>
```

in php code should be like this :

```
<?
    $radio = $_POST['radio'];
    $query = mysql_query('update "your table" set column1=$radio WHERE some_column=some_value);
?>
```