# Querying Radio buttons into MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need advice to use radio buttons in html to query into MYSQL base on the user selection.

The table is called "Trainers"

There are Three trainers:

1. krillavilla
2. Novac
3. Urie

The user choose what trainer he/she want to setup a meeting with. On the MYSQL I want to show the "krillavilla" got "5" meetings with users and "Urie" got "0" meetings with users.

I research this post:
[How can i add radio buttons record into MySQL fields using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060436/how-can-i-add-radio-buttons-record-into-mysql-fields-using-php) 
but I was trying to avoid arrays

And on this post: 
[Inserting the selection of radio buttons into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042001/inserting-the-selection-of-radio-buttons-into-mysql)

Doesnt answer my question what I am looking for.

This is my php:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","******","******","*****");//This is the login creditial 

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());//Error check for execution 
}

// Escape user inputs for security

$trainers = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['trainers']);




// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO trainers (trainers) VALUES ('$trainers')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
    <p>

        <input type="radio" name="trainers" id="krillavilla">krillavilla
    </p>
    <p>

        <input type="radio" name="trainers" id="Urie">Urie
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="trainers" id="Novac">Novac
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>us
</html>
```

This is my second form page. I am trying to create a GYM schedule using three form webpages where the user will:

Sign up a membership=> User Select the trainer=> User selected what type of membership he/she wants=> confirmation page

but for now i need help of figuring out how can i get my radio buttons data to record how many users that assign to trainer on MYSQL.

BTW I used this:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php

as my guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to set `value="Urie"` instead of `id="Urie"`

Comment: Thanks...if you are happy please add it as accepted answers.